# Proxy SQL for Oracle DB

Tags: oracle

I am developing java applications which connect to Oracle databases. Application loads some amount of data on startup. Because of slow connection to TEST environment, applications start up take some time. 
I am looking if there is some proxy/cache tool, which would locally store results for every query. So it could load result from memory if query was already called, instead of calling DB again. This could save a lot of time.
I guess ProxySQL does something similar but it is targeted for MySQL. Is there something for Oracle DB ?

Comment: Oracle Coherence, Oracle Result Cache, Terracota

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Oracle Client Result Cache.  It works with the JDBC OCI driver.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGDBA/tune_result_cache.htm#TGDBA626

Comment: If I understand that correctly, Oracle Client Result Cache is tight with application. So when application is shut down or restarted, cache is cleared. Therefore it is completely useless in my case.